# How to vacuum room with minimal amount of effort?

Tags: cleaning, home, efficiency

I'm trying to find any life hacks which helps me to safe time on [vacuuming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuum_cleaner) the room. Especially if you need to repeat the work every few days over and over again.

I'm not talking about the right posture or time management, but physical things which could help with that.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Think about your floor as grid paper:

[image]

Each square as wide as the head of your vacuum. Vacuum around objects as to best avoid retracing squares. After a while, you'll get used to the layout of a room.

The only physical "hacks" would be to choose your outlet wisely so you don't trip over the power cord.

Answer (score 3):

Don't try to do it too fast. If you swipe too fast it won't pick up all the dust and you have to do that part of the floor again.

Also don't let the dustbag get too full or you will lose suction.

Clean/replace the filters, to keep suction high.

Declare part of your house "no-go", live in the kitchen, less use of an area means less cleaning.

Answer (score 0):

You can do a lot to reduce the build up of dust in the first place, and then to make it easier to remove.

Start by removing rugs and carpets where possible. Hard floors are much easier to clean as they don't trap dust. If you need rugs or carpets you can get types that both produce and trap less dust.

On a similar note, you can also try to reduce the amount of dust from furnishings by switching to leather and wood instead of cloth and fabric. Clean/change filters on air conditioners and ventilation regularly. Switch to blinds instead of curtains, and try to keep windows shut.

Try to keep your floor area clean. The more obstacles the more effort it will be to clean. Also try to avoid areas, particularly gaps, that are hard to access with the vacuum cleaner.

Finally, get a good vacuum cleaner with good accessories. For example, you can get attachments for vacuuming furniture, for doing on top of large items like wardrobes, and of course the right head for the type of floor you are cleaning. Some have specific features that make your life easier - Dyson's lift more dust from carpets in my experience, while Japanese manufacturers like Panasonic and Hitachi offer dust sensors so you know when an area is clean and you can move on without wasted effort.

Answer (score -2):

My advice would be to invest [Robot Vacuum](http://robot-vacuum-review.toptenreviews.com/). This will make your life easier by giving your boring task of cleaning floors to the robot. Some of them can clean your whole house while you are gone and when you back after a busy work, it's great to see your floors clean.

Usually the've the following useful cleaning capabilities such as:

- Operating Pattern such as Virtual Map, Back and Forth or Random,
- Scheduled Cleaning (you can program to operate at certain days or time),
- Height Adjustment (some of them can move from one type of flooring to another),
- Cliff Sensor (preventing falling from the stairs),
- Return to Charging Base (some of them can automatically return to their base to recharge),
- Virtual Walls (you can place small devices at the places which robot should avoid),
- Remote Control (you can use remote controller to control them, even when you're on the holidays),
- and many more.

Comment: Hm....I don't know how much of a "hack" this really is....it's not mainstream (as far as I'm aware), but it's also kinda expensive (as far as I know). ....have anything else to suggest?

Comment: Interesting hack in terms of that it isn't a common solution (at least in EU) as many people are not aware of vacuum robots (most of my friends didn't know about it). Not expensive if you buy used one on eBay (there are many brands and models). In future I hope we'll have [Ex Machina-like](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0470752/) sexy vacuum models.